# How to request header set in middleware to route.js nextjs 13

Tags: javascript, next.js, middleware, next.js13

I want to get the request headers set in **middleware.js** file into the **route.js** file in nextjs 13. I checked the documentation and copied the following code.

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export function middleware(request) {
  console.log("middleware called");
  // Clone the request headers and set a new header `x-hello-from-middleware1`
  const requestHeaders = new Headers(request.headers);
  requestHeaders.set("requestHeaderValue", "hello");

  // You can also set request headers in NextResponse.rewrite
  const response = NextResponse.next({
    request: {
      // New request headers
      headers: requestHeaders,
    },
  });

  // Set a new response header `x-hello-from-middleware2`
  response.headers.set("requestHeaderValue", "hello");
  return response;
}

// See "Matching Paths" below to learn more
export const config = {
  matcher: "/products/:path*",
};
```

And then trying to access this **requestHeaderValue** in the route.js file as follow

```
import { headers } from 'next/headers'
 
export async function GET(request) {
  const headersList = headers()
  const value = headersList.get('requestHeaderValue')

  console.log(value)
 
  return new Response('Hello, Next.js!', {
    status: 200,
    headers: { referer: value },
  })
}
```

I get **null** when I console log the value in my route.js